# array with o(1)

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to find the sum of a random subset in a 2D array in o(1) complexity, size up to array[1000][1000] but lets take [4][4] as a basic example:

```
array[4][4] = {0, 1, 2 ,3
              4, 5, 6, 7
              8, 9, 10, 11
              12, 13, 14, 15}
```

I have seen some implementations for 1 dimensional arrays where you store the running sum and then just subtract.

That makes sense but lets say I want the sum of `array[2][2]` to `array[3][3]` in o(1). So it'd be 10 + 11 + 14 + 15.

But how can this be done in o(1)? o(n) is easy.

Is it something to do with hash tables or a more complicated pre-processed array?

edit>>>

Just some additioanl notes for anyone who comes back to this question:

1. The specific wording that is useful when googling this seems to be 'summed-area table' or 'integral image' or 'Viola–Jones object detection framework'
2. Useful references include https://computersciencesource.wordpress.com/2010/09/03/computer-vision-the-integral-image/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed-area_table

Comment: If the max array size is [4][4] you're better off doing this naively with a for loop and letting the compiler optimize it for you instead of pre-computing the sum of every subset

Comment: Hi yes but I am trying to solve it without compiler optimisations. I am also aware you can use pointers instead of indexing the array.
The main point is not go make o(n) faster but to make it o(1) no matter the size of the array if it is [10][10] or [1000][1000]

Comment: "o(1) no matter the size of the array" If the array size is fixed, a for loop is already o(1) anyway. If you're talking about a different array size, then don't state max array size [4][4] in your question.

Comment: Okay I have clarified my question with these details

Comment: If we beforehand know input size of something, it yields constant time complexity, i.e. O(1). So, loop usage doesn't always result in O(n) time comp.

Comment: "Size up to array[1000][1000]" Using the most naive method to sum up all elements, then the complexity is `O(1000 * 1000)=O(1)`.

Comment: Yes but the issue is if you need to take a sub section within that array, not just the whole array

Comment: Is the problem not to find the sum of the elements in an arbitrary subset but to find the sum of the elements in a contiguous subarray, that is, the sum of all elements `array[i][j]` for i0 ≤ i < i1 and j0 ≤ j ≤ j1 for some given i0, i1, j0, and j1?

Comment: yes - that is correct Eric

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It's worse: `o(1) != O(1)`. `o(1)` would be a *decreasing* function like `1/n`. Just examining every element of an array takes O(n) time; you can't do anything with all the values in constant, O(1) time.

Comment: @chepner I have no idea what you're talking about... but just to clarify, the original question implied the array size was a fixed value, which would mean that accessing all the elements would be indeed o(1) _and_ O(1).

Comment: You can still discuss the algorithm's complexity if you don't assume that all the inputs will always be 4x4, which is what the OP is asking about, given the comment "[O](n) is easy". @JiPecki `o(1)` and `O(1)` are two different notations. Assumptions about the input size aside, you cannot add up all the elements in an arbitrary array in less than O(n) time, because it takes that long just to *look* at each element, let alone do anything with them. Contrast this with things like O(lg n) bounds for binary search, because binary search *doesn't* require looking at every element.

Comment: @chepner the point is it wasn't clarified that the array size was arbitrary.. I'm done discussing this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For each element `[i][j]`, precompute the sum of all elements in the rectangle spanning from `array[0][0]` to `array[i][j]`; denote this value `sums[i][j]`.  Then, to compute the sum of a *rectangular* subset `i1 <= i <= i2` and `j1 <= j <= j2`, compute:

```
sums[i2][j2] 
- (i1 == 0 ? 0 : sums[i1 - 1][j2]) 
- (j1 == 0 ? 0 : sums[i2][j1 - 1]) 
+ ((i1 == 0 || j1 == 0) ? 0 : sums[i1-1][j1-1])
```

The bounds checks are used to avoid an illegal access outside of array bounds when the region of interest includes `i==0` or `j==0`.

As a rough geometric argument, see the below figure. To get the sum in the black rectangle, get the orange rectangle, subtract the red and green ones, and add back the purple one (since it got double-subtracted).

[image]

Comment: This could be thought of as the inclusion–exclusion principle. The diagram is really helpful.