# Average of a subset in an array which is out of bounds with constant complexity

Tags: c, arrays, pixel

This is a follow up question to my previous issue to do with 2d array processing techqniques with o(1) complexity.

That is to get the **average** of a subset of an array but if this subset extends beyond the bounds of an array taking those as zero. This is with a 2D array.

In reality the array can go up to [2000][2000] but lets take a 2D array that is sized [4][4] for simplicity.

```
array[4][4] = {0,  1,  2,  3
               4,  5,  6,  7
               8,  9,  10, 11
               12, 13, 14, 15}
```

Now let's say I want to get the sum of the array between [2][2] and [3][3], i.e. adding 10 + 11 + 14 + 15 and dividing by four. This can be made in a o(1) solution by using a 'summed area table' or 'integral image' techniques.

However I am little confused about how to keep this o(1) complexity providing/when:

1. the array subset extends outside the actual array
2. the array indices outside the actual array are taken as zero.
3. The algorithm computation is still o(1)

So for example lets say for this pixel sum I am asked to get the sum of [2][2] to [4][4]. This has a theoretical array of, numbers outside actual are denoted f (for fake) **but are taken as zero**:

```
array_theory[5][5] = {0,  1,  2,  3,  0f
                      4,  5,  6,  7,  0f
                      8,  9,  10, 11, 0f
                      12, 13, 14, 15, 0f
                      0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f}
```

or in an image:
[image]

So now the average between [2][2] and [4][4] is (10 + 11 + 0f + 14 + 15 + 0f + 0f + 0f + 0f)/ 9

I think I have to use some sort of filter or image processing technique that I can't seem to a key word to allow me to find/implement it and am flirting with it in my search results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need four variables: Starting row, ending row, start position in row, and end position in row. If you have these four variables, you can write a generic algorithm.

Comment: Yes the issue is that it needs to be constant comlexity i.e. o(1). Regardless of how many zeroes or how far it goes. It can't check each individual position in the array or extended 'fake' array.

Comment: I think the solution is just to limit the end position by the array size, which then leads to the same problem addressed in your previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The solution you have been given previously to compute the sum of the elements in a subarray with one corner at `array[i0][j0]` and another corner at `array[i1][j1]` in O(1) time after prior preparation is to prepare an array `sums` in which `sums[i][j]` is the sum of all elements in the subarray `array[0][0]` to `array[i][j]`, after which the sum of an arbitrary subarray may be computed as `sums[i1][j1] - sums[i1][j0-1] - sums[i0-1][j1] + sums[i0-1][j0-1]`, except that any of those terms is replaced with `0` if either of its subscripts is less than zero.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60267109/298225)

To extend this beyond the greater edges of the array, simply clamp the terms to their maximums: If any subscript exceeds the last valid index of the array, replace it with the last valid index of the array.

We might define an auxiliary function to access `sums`:

```
/*  Return sums[i][j] from an array that is physically r rows and c columns
    but is conceptually extended infinitely on all four sides as if
    arrays[i][j] contained zeros for all elements outside the physical
    array.
*/
Type Sums(ssize_t r, ssize_t c, Type sums[r][c], ssize_t i, ssize_t j)
{
    if (i < 0 || j < 0) return 0;
    if (r <= i) i = r-1;
    if (c <= j) j = c-1;
    return sums[i][j];
}
```

Then the sum of the elements in the subarray from `array[i0][j0]` to `array[i1][j1]` is simply `Sums[i1][j1] - Sums[i1][j0-1] - Sums[i0-1][j1] + Sums[i0-1][j0-1]`, and the average is of course `(Sums[i1][j1] - Sums[i1][j0-1] - Sums[i0-1][j1] + Sums[i0-1][j0-1]) / ((j1-j0+1) * (i1-i0+1))`.